# Applicable method for the clustering of time-series consisting of multiple events

Tags: clustering, time-series

I'm currently dealing with a time-series clustering problem at work and I need help with picking/suggesting the right methodology. The problem is similar to clustering of users on a website based on their actions.

Each user is uniquely identified by his IP (oversimplification) and is represented by a time series of actions. An action could be anything from going to homepage, adding an item into his shopping cart, sending a form. An action has other features - e.g. time at which it was done, or what items were added into the shopping cart.

One time series could therefore look like this:

```
User receives goes to https://www.example.com, 
from there he goes into https://www.example.com/categories, 
https://www.example.com/some-product and he adds this product into the cart.
```

Each action was separated by 5-10 seconds. The behaviour pattern is completely different from a crawler, which would look like this:
`Homepage, Category1, Category2, Category3 ... CategoryN`, each with exactly 2 seconds between any two events.

Is there a unsupervised learning method which could be used for clustering users into N groups, depending on the characteristics of their behaviour? The closest I got so far are the self-organizing maps, though they do not really put much emphasis on time.

Thanks, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.